# Rails How can one query association definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

I have a lot of dynamic code which keeps complex relations in a string.
ex:

```
 "product.country.continent.planet.galaxy.name"
```

How can I check if these relations exist?
I want a method like the following:

```
  raise "n00b" unless Product.has_associations?("product.country.planet.galaxy")
```

How could I implement this?

Comment: I think we need more code here, what kind of association are you storing in the string? active record associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def has_associations?(assoc_str)
  klass = self.class
  assoc_str.split(".").all? do |name| 
    (klass = klass.reflect_on_association(name.to_sym).try(:klass)).present?
  end
end
```

Comment: just replaced reflect_on_association(name) by reflect_on_association(name.to_sym) and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If these are active record associations, here's how you can do it:

```
current_class = Product
has_associations = true
paths = "country.planet.galaxy".split('.')

paths.each |item|
  association = current_class.reflect_on_association( item )
  if association
    current_class = association.klass
  else
    has_associations = false
  end
end

puts has_association
```

And this will tell you if this specific path has all the associations.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed you are storing the AR associations in a string like that, this code placed in an initializer should let you do what you want. For the life of me I can't quite figure out why you'd want to do this, but I trust you have your reasons.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.has_associations?(relation_string="")
    klass = self
    relation_string.split('.').each { |j|
      # check to see if this is an association for this model
      # and if so, save it so that we can get the class_name of
      # the associated model to repeat this step
      if assoc = klass.reflect_on_association(j.to_sym)
        klass = Kernel.const_get(assoc.class_name)
      # alternatively, check if this is a method on the model (e.g.: "name")
      elsif klass.instance_method_already_implemented?(j)
        true
      else
        raise "Association/Method #{klass.to_s}##{j} does not exist"
      end
    }
    return true
  end
end
```

With this you'll need to leave off the initial model name, so for your example it would be:

```
Product.has_associations?("country.planet.galaxy")
```